# How do you apply potion effects to players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm developing a minigame server. I just need to know what commands to use, via command block, to give players special effects infinitely such as: speed boost, regeneration, or jump boost. I know it's possible, I've played on games that use these things, or is it a mod?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the command:

- Speed boost: `/effect @p 1 100 10`
- Jump boost: `/effect @p 8 100 5`

Note: this doesn't work on bedrock

Source: [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzv4CqpTNN8%E2%80%8E)

If you want to read more about command blocks and effects take a look here:

[Command Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block)

[Command Block Tutorials](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_Block)

[Status Effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect)

Comment: But how do you give status effects indefinitely, infinitely, without time limit?

Comment: @Prodias if you want to give a player an effect infinitely, just set the effect duration to a number over 372000.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms The display in the inventory will show `**:**` if the duration could not be parsed as a signed Short (max of 32,767). It is **not** infinite and cannot be infinite on its own. A clock must be used to constantly re-apply the effect.

Comment: As of 1.13, the syntax for effects has changed. The commands are now `/effect give @p minecraft:speed 100 10` and `/effect give @p minecraft:jump_boost 100 5`

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
/effect @a minecraft:jump_boost 2 10
```

This gives Jump boost two to all players for 10 seconds. The command is

```
/effect (player, @a or @p) minecraft:(potion, with _ between two words) (level of potion such as jump boost 2 or 3) (number of seconds, 255 max, more for unlimited)
```

Answer (score 0):

/effect give @a minecraft:jump_boost

@a means all players, you can also use @p (nearest player) or @e (all entities)

you can replace jump_boost with any potion effect (like slow_falling poison speed_boost)

Answer (score -1):

`/effect @p {ID Number} {Number of seconds} 10` Switch the 10 out if you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is my way. I'm using regeneration

First type this command in:
/effect @e regeneration 120 [hideparticles]

Then, put the command block on a clock system

I never tried it so if it doesn't work, just say it in the comments and I'll fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Without time limit you make the time in the command as shown above from 10 to 100000000. Not preciesly so many zeros but much.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if this is what your looking for, but here it goes:

For speed effect: `/effect @p 1`

If you want it for longer or faster, do it like this: `/effect @p 1 255 10`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

Speed Effect:

`/effect @p 1 10 100`

You can swap the 10 with any higher number. This specifically is how many seconds the effect lasts.

Comment: First off, this doesn't provide a complete answer to the question, but that's not the main focus. The part I'm focussing on is the fact this does not provide anything more that the other answers haven't already provided. And what "Notch's Twin Sister's Goldfish"? Is that a signature?

Comment: @Ben it reads like a Ask GGSP signature. either way it doesn't add anything to the question especially since time has been taken to format it (unlike answer where personal information is added as just plain text)

Comment: In that case I would suggest removing it then. It's not a practise on this site, and will most likely just attract the same reaction as I have given.